# How do I list all package names in a specific category using Terminal?

Tags: command-line, apt

How do I list all package names in one section? If, for example, I want to list all applications in section "web", which command do I need to input?

Comment: What are those "sections" you mention?

Comment: Enter cache, the information of Firefox, including description, Priority, Section.... This Section is what I means

Comment: ok, i means How to retrieve a list of installed packages on ubuntu sorted by category

Answer (score -1):

**In terminal  type:**

```
apt-cache search 'web'
```

It will list all packages in this category and its usage.

Change "web" with the category you want.

Comment: How is `dragonplayer`, or `amarok` or others from your output related to "web"?

Comment: maybe its considered by many categories

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not do what you think it does. Have a look at `man apt-cache`. The `search` section explains that it looks through the package names and descriptions. It does not in any way look for categories. That's why this command returns 3249 packages instead of the 1754 that are actually in the "Web" category.